# How to show values of data (from array) into plot on matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

HI there i want to ask about how to show values of data that i sorted in an array to the plot?
i've try use text but not work

```
 for sv=1:trialsv
        figure('Name',sprintf('Figure Sensitivitas ke-%d',sv),'NumberTitle','off')
        set(gcf,'renderer','zbuffer');
        for js=1:3
            fprintf('\nSensitivitas dengan metode %s di posisi F(%d,%d)\n',methodnames{js},inputv(sv),inputt(sv))
            for tr=1:trial
                methods{tr}=sprintf('Nilai uji ke-%d = %f\n',tr,MatrixIterF{tr,js}(vi(sv),ti(sv)));
                fprintf(methods{tr});
                plMatrixIterF(tr,js)=MatrixIterF{tr,js}(vi(sv),ti(sv));
            end
            plot(sce(1:trial,scenario),plMatrixIterF(1:trial,js), strcat(colors(length(colors)-js+1),syms(js)));
            strValues=strtrim(cellstr(num2str([sce(1:trial,scenario) plMatrixIterF(1:trial,js)],'(%d,%d)')));
            text(sce(1:trial,scenario),plMatrixIterF(1:trial,js),'VerticalAlignment','bottom');
            hold all
        end
        title(strcat('Plot sensitivitas terhadap ',scetype(scenario),sprintf(' di posisi F(%d,%d)',inputv(sv),inputt(sv))))
        xlabel(xlabels)
        ylabel('Nilai Undeveloped Proyek')
        legend(methodnames,'Location','NorthEast');
        grid on
    end
```

Comment: Do you want to use a selfdefined axis? or do you want to show "text/values" as annotation in your plot?

Comment: I want to show the value from the result that i've save in location plMatrixIterF(1:trial,js)
`
 strValues=strtrim(cellstr(num2str([sce(1:trial,scenario) plMatrixIterF(1:trial,js)],'(%d,%d)')));
       text(sce(1:trial,scenario),plMatrixIterF(1:trial,js),'VerticalAligAlignment','bottom');`

Comment: i'm confuse how ho write the command to show the value on the mark point on the graph... so i try add these 2 lines but i thought it's wrong,

Comment: almost the same problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19062382/matlab-drawing-points-and-show-values but not solved yet

Comment: DO you look for sth. like this: http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/creating_plots/adding-text-to-graphs.html ?

Comment: yeah right, thanks a lot for your help :D; i've solved it after trying..

Comment: text(sce(1:trial,scenario),plMatrixIterF(1:trial,js),sprintf('(%0.f)',plMatrixIterF(1:trial,js))      work for me !! thanks all